# How to configure Oracle SQL Developer to access my Apex database in the cloud?

Tags: sql, oracle, cloud, oracle-apex

I'm using a macbook and because I don't want to install a virtual machine to have an Oracle XE running (I don't have enough space in my HD), I subscribed in the APEX service. So I have two questions:
1. How can I load a dump in the server? I just found a SQL place, but nothing about dumps...
2. How can I use the SQL Developer cloud service to manage my cloud database? I'm not seeing where can I find the information requested in the screen:

[image: parameters]

Comment: What is the "APEX service" that you are referring to?  If you are talking about apex.oracle.com, Oracle doesn't provide direct access to the database behind that.  You'd have to do everything through the APEX builder web app.  If you are referring to some other hosted service, please explain exactly what service you're using.  There are dozens of companies that will host an APEX site for you, each of which may have a different answer.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for reply. Yes, I'm talking about the apex.oracle.com. I was researching more and I discovered that if I give "SQL Developer" access to my user, I can access my database. But I'm not sure about the URL and SFTP parameters. That's my doubt... I've found part of the explanation here: [link](http://multikoop.blogspot.com/2012/11/oracle-java-and-database-cloud-services.html)

Comment: That link is for the Oracle Cloud service which is a commercial product (with a free 30-day trial option).  apex.oracle.com is a free service that does not provide direct database access.  They are two completely different services.